# AngularJS form submit not working with JQuery validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation, angularjs

I have one AngularJS application. I have a registration page.

looks like this

**register.html**

```
<form id="userRegistration" ng-submit="registerUser()" >
<fieldset>
    <label class="block clearfix">
        <span class="block">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Username" ng-model="user.username" name="username" placeholder="Username" required="required" />
        </span>
    </label>

    <label class="block clearfix">
        <span class="block">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" ng-model="user.password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required="required" />
        </span>
    </label>

    <label class="block clearfix">
        <span class="block">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" ng-model="user.email" name="emailId" placeholder="Email" required="required" />
        </span>
    </label>
    <div class="clearfix">
        <button type="reset" class="width-48 pull-left btn btn-sm">
            Reset
        </button>

        <button type="submit" class="width-48 pull-right btn btn-sm btn-success">
            Register
        </button>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

I am using [this wraspbootstrap theme](http://wrapbootstrap.com/preview/WB0B30DGR). It has form validations. That validation I am using. I have given my rules in page itself.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $.mask.definitions['~']='[+-]';
    $('#phone').mask('(999) 999-9999');

    jQuery.validator.addMethod("phone", function (value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || /^\(\d{3}\) \d{3}\-\d{4}( x\d{1,6})?$/.test(value);
    }, "Enter a valid phone number.");

    $('#userRegistration').validate({
        errorElement: 'div',
        errorClass: 'help-block',
        focusInvalid: false,
        rules: {
            userName:{
                required: true,
            },
            password: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
            },
            emailId: {
                required: true,
                email:true
            }
        },

        messages: {
            userName:{
                required:"Please choose a user name."
            },
            password: {
                required: "Please specify a password.",
                minlength: "Please specify a password of atleast 5 character."
            },
            emailId: {
                required: "Please provide email.",
                email: "Please provide a valid email."
            }
        },

        invalidHandler: function (event, validator) { //display error alert on form submit   
            $('.alert-danger', $('.login-form')).show();
        },

        highlight: function (e) {
            $(e).closest('label.block').addClass('has-error');
        },

        success: function (e) {
            $(e).closest('label.block').removeClass('has-error');
            $(e).remove();
        },

        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            if(element.is(':checkbox') || element.is(':radio')) {
                var controls = element.closest('div[class*="col-"]');
                if(controls.find(':checkbox,:radio').length > 1) controls.append(error);
                else error.insertAfter(element.nextAll('.lbl:eq(0)').eq(0));
            }
            else if(element.is('.select2')) {
                error.insertAfter(element.siblings('[class*="select2-container"]:eq(0)'));
            }
            else if(element.is('.chosen-select')) {
                error.insertAfter(element.siblings('[class*="chosen-container"]:eq(0)'));
            }
            else error.insertAfter(element.parent());
        },

        submitHandler: function (form) {
        },
        invalidHandler: function (form) {
        }
    });

});
</script>
```

When I click on submit button, the Jquery validation is hapening and error messages coming. But at the same time, it is calling `registerUser()` method in angularJS and posting the user in controller.

This is my controller JS **register.js**

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('RegisterController', function($scope,$http) {
    page.setPage("Register","login-layout");
    $scope.user = {};
    $scope.registerUser=function()
    {
       alert("Submitting...");
    }
});
```

It always alerts the message whenever I click the submit button, even if the form is invalid. The validation happens only if I click on submit button only. So how can I call the method only if the form is valid?

Comment: You need to check the validity again in `registerUser` method as: `if (!$("#userRegistration").valid()) return;`

Comment: Inside my controller?

Comment: Thanks. Got it. I could accept as answer if it is a comment :)

Comment: No worries buddy. I'm just glad I could help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**UPDATE**

I found a better way without JQuery. I found this answer long back, but now I remembered to update here after a year. The forms will be available in `$scope` object. So just give a name to the form and use it.

**HTML**

```
<form id="userRegistration" name="registration" ng-submit="registerUser()" >
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.registerUser=function()
    {
       if ($scope.registration.$valid){
           alert("Submitting...");
       }
    }
```

**OLD Answer**

Thanks to [srvikram](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1990505/srvikram13) for the comment. I am adding the comment as answer here.

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('RegisterController', function($scope,$http) {
    page.setPage("Register","login-layout");
    $scope.user = {};
    $scope.registerUser=function()
    {
       if ($("#userRegistration").valid()){
           alert("Submitting...");
       }
    }
});
```